# Return value of getClasses() in R?

Tags: r, r-s4

`getClasses()` returns the all the classes visible from the calling function, the return value is in the "character" class.

However, it is different when directly displaying the structure of an return values and when displaying the assigned variables. Why is that? (see the following code)

```
str(getClasses())
#chr(0) 

all_classes <- getClasses()
str(all_classes)
#chr [1:128] "refMethodDefWithTrace" "numeric" ...
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. `str(getClasses())` returns the same for me like `str(all_classes)`, which is `chr [1:127] "<-" "(" "{" ...` for me.

Comment: @PatrickRoocks I used R version 3.3.2, freshly restarted and only with the basic package loaded. It still showed the same result as my post. It is on Windows 7 platform, btw